# How to shorten `import qualified`?

Tags: haskell, c-preprocessor, template-haskell

I want to sort my imports by name, qualified and unqualified

```
import           A
import qualified B
import           C
import qualified D
```

But there are big gaps in code, and lines are long, so I want to shorten it

```
{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}
#define importq import qualified

import  A
importq B
import  C
importq D
```

It looks great, but now I get error from CPP

```
error: invalid preprocessing directive #!
#!/usr/bin/env runhaskell
^
phase `C pre-processor' failed (exitcode = 1)
```

if I want to run my program with help of shebang. CPP confilcts with shebangs.

How to deal with this problem? Is there another simple macro system allowing to make an alias `importq = import qualified`? Or is there another way to shorten `import qualified`?

Comment: no... just get used to it, that's the language.

Comment: The problem here is not just the shortening of `import qualified`, but the fact that `runhaskell` scripts seem to be incompatible with CPP because of the shebang. This looks as a bug of `runhaskell`, IMO, which should remove the shebang before calling CPP.